# Ant Design Table expanded change CSS class | React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, datatables, antd

I'm using [ant design](https://ant.design/components/table/#Note) in my project. There I'm using [DataTable](https://ant.design/components/table/).

It has row expand feature.

**Problem**

When user expand the child row, the parent row background color needs to be changed or else needs to add css class for that row.

[**Fiddle Here**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQYKPZ)

I have created function `onExpand` of the table.

```
  onExpand = (expanded, record) => {
    alert(expanded);
    console.log('onExpand', expanded, record);   }
```

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the **onRow** property to add a custom css class for each expanded row. First of all you need distinguish the expanded rows from the collapsed one. Therefore you have to store the keys of the expanded rows in the state to assign the css class to the right rows. For that purpose you have to use **expandedRowKeys** and **onExpand** properties too.

You can check the working example overhere:

https://codesandbox.io/s/2xyy8mqwoj

Comment: Could you add an example of how to control the expended row color as well?

Comment: when checking your working example. seems like when you hover on expended row, it gets another color. i would like to have a way to contorl the hover color and "mouse at rest" on this expended row, any ideas?